# WPF ColumnDataPoint Annotation partial visible

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit, data-visualization

I have chart with column series in my application. I'm using solution from this tutorial to add annotation on top of columns:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/07/27/simple-column-labels-you-can-create-at-home-re-templating-the-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-columndatapoint-to-add-annotations.aspx

When the bar is really tall the top part of the annotation is only partial visible, or not visible.

[image]

I do not know range of my data, so I can not set Maximum value on the vertical Axis.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Now I have no idea how to fix but the problem is the negative margin. Maybe you can use an other container than Grid in the ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Like Andre said, the problem is your Margin, so you could use Multibinding to calculate the Margin like so:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:ColumnDataPoint">
      <Grid>
          <Rectangle Name="clmnRectangle"
                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                     Stroke="Black"/>
          <Grid Background="#aaffffff"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
              <Grid.Margin>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HeightToMargin}">
                       <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type charting:ColumnDataPoint}}"></Binding>
                       <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type charting:ColumnSeries}}"></Binding>
                  </MultiBinding>
              </Grid.Margin>
              <TextBlock Name="tbValue"
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Margin="2"/>
         </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The Converter could look like:

```
public class HeightToMarginConverter:IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        double clmnHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]);
        double chrtHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
        if (chrtHeight - clmnHeight < 20)
        {
            return new Thickness(0, clmnHeight - chrtHeight + 5, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Thickness(0, -20, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it is the problem with margin. But I want to show annotation outsite bar, even if bar is tall.